# What is the http request and response body for this URL request?

Tags: http, tomcat

I would like to view/understand the HTTP request & response body formats that get transmitted between browser and tomcat server.

When I ran this URL request

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/images/code.gif
```

From the browser, I see the request line & header as

```
GET /manager/images/code.gif HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=F0140CCF2977AFA053F79DB9A0C74DD0
```

And response status & header as:

```
http 1.1 200/OK

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:394
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Sun, 04 May 2014 02:20:57 GMT
ETag:W/"394-1382091566000"
Last-Modified:Fri, 18 Oct 2013 10:19:26 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

My question is:

1. What will be the Request Message body for the URL request submitted? (content)
2. What will be the Response Message body from the tomcat server? (content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There will be no body. Only POST and PUT requests have a body.
2. The response body contains 394 bytes, which are the bytes of the gif image requested.